# Displaying a custom drop down list in a Woocommerce product table

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to display a custom drop down list in a woo-commerce product table for customer's to make a selection before adding product to cart. I have installed the Advanced Custom Field plugin and the Woo-commerce Product Table Pro. I do not want to use woo-commerce's product variation feature.

Does anyone know how I can display the custom drop down list I created in the product table?

Answer (score -1):

You just need [WC Fields Factory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/) Woocommerce extension which helps to add custom fields to your Product Page, using which you can gather additional information from the users while they adding the product to Cart.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but will it work in the woocommerce product table? The products are listed using the product table plugin. So the drop down list should be in one of the columns.

Comment: Yes I think so it should have to work, please try it out and let me know.

Comment: The fields come up on the single product page but I am not getting it to display in the product table.